# Is there a service that can sign my application for Apple enterprise distribution

Tags: app-store, enterprise, in-house-distribution

My app has been permanently rejected by Apple because of rules that conflict with my app's functionality. I need distribute my app outside of the AppStore. Is there a service that provides distribution in this fashion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Legally speaking (per Apple's Ts&Cs) you would have to sign up for an Enterprise Developer Account by calling Apple Developer Relations at 1 (800) 633-2152 (Mon-Fri 9:00AM-7:00PM CST). From there you can deploy your app via B2B to other businesses who have a VPP account without distributing through the App Store.

If you're looking to distribute to end-users you're now treading down the Cydia / jailbreak route. If you sign up for an Enterprise Developer account and just distribute your app via webserver, email, etc you run a good risk of wasting your $300 and getting your cert shut down.